# IOS objective-C execute GCD only when ViewController is visible

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm implementing a timeout function for my project using Objective-C (May be Swift in the future). The purpose is that if a we run a function (display an alert whenever a ViewController is present or has not been dismiss. We wait for 15 sec.

Here is my function

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(15 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

     // Do somework

    });
```

How can we ensure the function is only invoke if the viewController still visible or any better way to run the code avoiding retain cycle or memory leak?

Comment: If you just need to show an alert without delegate it won't harm it will still work as UIAlertView is not directly referenced to the ViewController, but if you set delegate you will get memory leak, so in that case you can check if `self` is available, call it else don't call it, or better move out the alert out of the ViewController execute in AppDelegate with having timer initialized only when you open the ViewController and destroyed when you go out of it, simple.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I need to show an alert with a button to goto another viewcontroller (only show alert when view is still on screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just call this in the viewcontroller you want to observe, put weak self in the block and if self is nil, the function simply wont execute mean your alert wont be showing:

```
__weak id weakSelf = self;
// or
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(15 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 

       [weakSelf doSth];

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. is the syntax correct. Tried your but have error

Comment: this one [weak self] may be it is in swift?

Comment: ah yes, I forgot yours is in obj-c, let me try convert it

Comment: there wont be a * in id. maybe you can use __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

Comment: hi implement your suggestion using __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self; and inside dispatch_after i use if (weakSelf!= nil) {//do something} the block still execute even when the view has been dismiss

Comment: you should call this in that vc class that is going to be dismissed, this get called because the self isn't deallocated yet

Comment: that quite strange. I use it on vc class that is going to be dismissed. I check on memory debugger the vc class still there and was deallocate only after the function run that mean the closure/block is the only one keep it alive?

Comment: quire strange indeed, weak self then it wont be captured strongly in the block, then it wont create retain cycle and should be deallocated